# Как создать регулярное выражение не по паттерну , а по строке?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, приходящая из `input`. Из неё надо сделать регулярку (аналог поиска). Однако если в поле ввести `+` или `\`, при создании регулярного выражения через `new RegExp` возникнет ошибка, так как этот конструктор принимает не строку, а паттерн.

Как добиться того, чтобы при вводе любой строки в `input` у меня создавалась регулярка на поиск этой строки?

Comment: `тк она принимает не строку , а паттерн` наоборот же как раз. строку оно принимает http://javascript.ru/regExp

Comment: если из любой входной строки надо получить валидный паттерн, то надо только заэкранировать спец.символы. тот же плюсик или бэкслеш.

Comment: Эх , надеялся есть еще какой то вариант ) Благодарю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заэкранируйте спец.символы в строке и получится валидная регулярка.

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

(C) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: +1 за создание регулярного выражения с помощью регулярного выражения

Comment: Только ``\/`` тут не нужен, его можно удалить => ``s.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')``